# Execute Lua script to delete all keys matching a pattern on Redis DB via stackexchange.redis

Tags: redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

I have a `Lua script` which deletes all keys matching a pattern. The script is the following:

```
EVAL "return redis.call('del', 'defaultKey', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))" 0 ad:*
```

This works fine within `redis-cli`, but I want to execute this within a `.NET` app using `StachExchange.Redis`.
I tried the following:

```
await db.ExecuteAsync("EVAL", "\"return redis.call('del', 'defaultKey', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))\" 0 ad:*");
```

but I get the following error

```
| Errormessage: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'eval' command
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
var script = "return redis.call('del', 'defaultKey', unpack(redis.call('keys', @keypattern)))";
var prepared = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
var noOfDeletedKeys = db.ScriptEvaluate(prepared, new { keypattern = (RedisKey)"ad:*" });
```